# When do we use the symbols $\geq$ and $\leq$ between the cardinality of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For example, I know that $\lvert \mathbb{R}\rvert > \lvert\mathbb{N}\rvert$, but is it also correct to state that $\lvert \mathbb{R}\rvert \geq \lvert\mathbb{N}\rvert$?

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: Sure, just as it’s correct to write $3\ge 2$. $|A|\le |B|$ means that there is an injection from $A$ to $B$; $|A|<|B|$ means that there is such an injection **and** there is no bijection.

Comment: See [Definition : $| A | ≤ | B |$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality#Definition_2:_.7C.E2.80.89A.E2.80.89.7C_.E2.89.A4_.7C.E2.80.89B.E2.80.89.7C).